# nextjs SSR how to cache stripe js V3

Tags: caching, next.js, stripe-payments, server-side-rendering

I have a getServiceSideProps to render a complex APP interacting with an API:

```
const MyApp: NextPage = (props: any) => {
    let stripePromise: any;
    const getStripe = async () => {
        if (!stripePromise) {
            stripePromise = await loadStripe(STRIPE_API_KEY);
        }
        return stripePromise;
    };

    const {t} = useTranslation(["generator"]);

    return (
        <>
            <NextSeo
                title={t("generator")}
                description={t("generator_intro")}
                canonical="url"
            />

            <main style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
                <Elements stripe={getStripe()}>
                    <GeneratorHeader />
                    <Generator />
                    <GeneratorFAQ />
                </Elements>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ locale, req, res }) => {

    res.setHeader(
        'Cache-Control',
        'public, s-maxage=86400'
    );

    return {
        props: {
            ...await serverSideTranslations(locale as string, ['generator', 'common', 'footer']),
        }
    }
}


export default MyApp
```

MyApp does request to an API and serves a stripe checkout payment page.

But when analysing the page with lighthouse, I see that all the stripes libraries have a TTL of "1m" despite trying to override `maxage`.

I'm unsure if I understood the nextjs documentation wrongly? How do you effectively cache js librairies with nextjs + SSR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to cache Stripe.js locally in your build or in a browser. That library is hosted by Stripe and has to be loaded directly from their server even if you use `loadStripe()`. This is required for security reasons and to meet the requirements for PCI compliance.

Comment: alright, thank you for this. So warning from lighthouse / google search can be ignored if it's related to stripe?

Comment: In that case yes, there is no way around it.